# page gets refreshed on submit click

Tags: javascript, validation

i have multiple validation on my form.. when i enter wrong data and click on submit button its shows the error message for a second and page gets refreshed..This is only few functions.there are other functions also.. Individually, they work fine. but when i try to run all , it doesnt work.

javascript:

```
function req() 
 {

if (document.reg_indi_form.txt_fnm.value=="") 
{

    document.getElementById('i').innerHTML="*This field is required";
    document.getElementById('i').style.color="red";
    document.getElementById('i').style.fontSize="12px";
}

if (document.reg_indi_form.txt_lnm.value=="") 
{

    document.getElementById('i1').innerHTML="*This field is required";
    document.getElementById('i1').style.color="red";
    document.getElementById('i1').style.fontSize="12px";
}
return false;
}

function validateUname() {
submitFlag = true;
var len=document.reg_indi_form.txt_usrnm.value.length;
if(len<6){
    submitFlag=false;
    document.getElementById('i2').innerHTML="*enter atleast 6 char";
    document.getElementById('i2').style.color="red";
   }
   return submitFlag;
  }



  function alls()
  {
req();
validateUname();


  }
```

html:

```
<form name="reg_indi_form" method="post" onSubmit="return alls()"         enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

There is also php code in my file.

Answer (score 1):

Change your function `alls()` to:

```
function alls()
  {
   return req() && validateUname(); // Your function must return false otherwise it will be considered as true
  }
```

Whenever you are binding event & want to stop propagation, just return false ( which you are doing ) but your function `alls()` was not returning anything which will not stop event propagation further.

Comment: Wouldn't this always return false, even if `validateUname()` returns true, as `req()` will return false?

Comment: Not returning anything doesn't mean true. A function without return statement will return `undefined`. And `undefined != true` and `undefined != false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `functions alls()` has no `return` statement and therefore returns an `undefined`. The only return value that prevents the default action is `false`. Any other return value, including `undefined`, allows the default action to take place.

change your function alls() to look like this:

```
function alls()  {
    req();
    return validateUname();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In function alls()

```
function alls()
  {
   return req() && validateUname(); //  Equivalent to--  if(req() && validateUname()) {return true;} else{ return false;}
  }
```